# How can I a remove a single element from an array if I have multiple elements with the same value?

Tags: arrays, swift

If I have an array like this, how can I remove just one of the 4:rs if I can't use .remove(at:):

```
let a = [3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 8, 7]
```

Comment: add values to Set, in set there is no duplicates

Comment: Why can you not use `remove(at:)` ??

Comment: If I code with swift

Comment: What if still want to have the array left with two of the 4:rs

Comment: I might not know which element it is so I don't know what number to use after at:

Comment: So your actual problem is how to find the position of the first “4“ in the array. Lookup the `firstIndex(of:)` method!

Comment: Firsts of all you need to change your array declaration from `let` to `var`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the index of the first element where value = 4 and then remove it. Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

var a = [3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 8, 7]
let b = a.firstIndex(of: 4)
if let b = b {
a.remove(at: b)
} else { 
print("value not present in array")
}
print(a)
```